# How to decide on number of threads for an application?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I have read that each core can have two threads. So, if my application in prod uses three octa core servers, does that mean my application can only handle 48 concurrent requests? Or am I mixing two different things here?

Would appreciate any clarity here.

Comment: Does your server keep each thread busy 100% of the time? If not, then you might be able to use more threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you can have as many threads as you like and you're not limited by how many CPU cores you have. I.e. Even if you only had one processor with a single core, you could still write a multi-threaded application.

The JVM will perform context switching - it will execute Thread 1 for some time, then Thread 2 for some time, then maybe Thread 1 again, and so on, switching between the threads. These switches between threads can occur after just a few milliseconds, so it can give the illusion that the threads are running in parallel.

On some applications, it is faster to just use a single thread - because this process of context switching just adds further expense.

I did actually write a small multi-threaded application the other day though. It had about 30 threads, and this was a use case where multithreading did make the app more efficient.

I had about 30 URLs that I needed to hit and retrieve some data from. If I did this in a single thread, there would be waiting time each time I made a request and waited for a response (thus, blocking the application). When multi-threading, other threads will have been able to run whilst this waiting went on.

I hope this makes sense. It'll be worth reading up on Java Context Switching for more info.

This is a good source on the topic: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Just a follow up question, how do we decide on number of threads for our application then? For eg. while using newfixedthreadpool in Executors, on what factors the count of number of threads depends?

Comment: I don't know to be honest. I ran my application on a single laptop, and it was able to handle 30 threads.  Of course, the more threads you have, the more memory you'll be using. I'd suggest trial and error - see how many you can push it with, before you see slowing down issues.